# pic24 debugger mode does not work

Tags: debugging, pic, mplab

I got a PICkit3, that I use for programming a `PIC24FJ64GA004` with MPLAB IDE 8.83 and the C30 compiler.

The debugger works with the following config bits:

`FNOSC` set to primary oscillator (XT HS EC) & 
`POSCMOD` set to HS osc

But I can't seem to get the debugger working with this config bit:

`FNOSC` set to primary oscillator with PLL module (HSPLL ECPLL).

It gives the following error when I run:

> PK3Err0040: The target device is not ready for debugging. Please check
>   your configuration bit settings and program the device before
>   proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

this error occurs when the clock is not running.  Check your clock circuit, make sure the pll parameters are such that the clock frequency is within the pics operating limits

Comment: the program works with the same setup, but written by the programmer instead of the debugger

Comment: I just started wrestling with an oddly similar problem (worked perfectly 2 months ago debug and program mode). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725464/pic16f18856-fails-to-program-when-wdt-off